# Why are finite stages of the Borel hierarchy $\bf{\Sigma}^0_n$ closed under bounded quantification?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Moschovakis proves in Theorem 1C.2 that the finite Borel pointclasses are closed under various operations, like continuous substitution, $\lor,\land,\neg$, etc. He runs the whole proof by induction, assuming that  $\bf{\Sigma}^0_n$ are all closed under the operations, and needing to prove that $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ are closed under them, too.

At the end of the proof, he claims that, assuming closure of $\bf{\Sigma}^0_n$ under $\exists^{\leq}$, then closure of $\bf{\Sigma}^0_{n+1}$ under $\exists^{\leq}$ is trivial. Why is this the case?

Comment: An application of $\exists^{\le}$ corresponds to a finite union, with one "disjunct" per number below the bound. E.g. "$\exists m<k(f(m)=0)$" is just "$\bigvee_{m<k}(f(m)=0)$" (or more set-theoretically, $\{f: \exists m<k(f(m)=0)\}=\bigcup_{m<k}\{f: f(m)=0\}$). And each of those disjuncts is of appropriate complexity ...